# Can I get rid of the last line of the iPhone keyboard or change the functionality of certain keys?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I'm developing my first iphone app, it is a word game, I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is anyway of using the apple keyboard but changing certain keys. The last line of the apple keyboard is redundant in the app I'm planning and is just taking up screen real estate. I need a done button but not a shift button(on the third line). Is there anyway to change keys and get rid of keys on the keyboard. I know Apple don't like 'custom' keyboards but can I customise a key or two without messing with the entire functionality of the keyboard. If I can get rid of a line that would be great if not can I replace keys like the space bar for a 'hint' button?

If I'm not allowed to add custom keys (like a hint button) to the keyboard can I get rid of the last line of the iPhone keyboard or change the functionality of certain keys?

I don't really know much about these things, I'm pretty new to it, so thank you for any help in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cant change Apple keyBoard key Functionality   system**, But your can change types of KeyBoard by

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the functionality of any key. But you can overlay above the keyboard and you can achieve some more functionality.

All the best !!!